# Sum of Poisson distributions

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, central-limit-theorem

The problem I have is the following:

> By applying the *central limit theorem* to a sequence of random variables with the Possion distribution, prove that
>   $$
> e^{-n}\left(1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{n^n}{n!}\right)\to\frac{1}{2}, \mbox{ as } n\to\infty
> $$

What I did so far:

If we chose $X \sim Poisson(n)$, then we have that 
$$
P(X = k) = \frac{n^k}{k!}e^{-n}
$$

Hence,

$$
P(X\leq n) = e^{-n}\left(1+n+\frac{n^2}{2!} + \dots + \frac{n^n}{n!}\right)
$$

And, we know that $E[X] = n$ and that $Var(X) = n$, hence 
$$
P(X\leq n) = P\left (\frac{X-E[X]}{\sqrt{var(X)}\sqrt{n}}\leq 0\right )
$$

Now, I know that we cannot take the limit in the probability as $X$ is not, yet a sum of independent random variables, but if we could write $X$ as a sum of independent random variables, then we would be able to have $P(X\leq n)\to \phi(0) = \frac{1}{2}$.

My understanding of the question is that it is required to find $X_1, X_2, \dots$ random variables, each a particular type of a Poisson distribution, so that added up, namely $X_1 + \dots + X_n = X$. Also, I know that a Poisson distribution can be written as a sum of independent Poisson distributions, however given that we have $X \sim Poisson(n)$ **can** we find **exactly** $n$ such distributions so that they add up to $X$ ? If so:

**How** do I find these *Poisson* distributions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea is to take a sequence of independent random variables
$X_1,X_2,\ldots$ each Poisson with mean $1$. Then $S_n=X_1+\cdots+X_n$
is Poisson with mean $n$ and one can then apply CLT.

Comment: Thank you! It was so obvious, no idea how I missed it.