Evaluation of limit of integrals where calculus tricks don't work
Suppose that we want to evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{n x^n}{1+x^3} \, dx$. Clearly the standard limit theorems for integration (Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem, monotone convergence theorem, etc.) don't work here, as the answer is $1/2$.  There's at least three ways to prove this converges to $1/2$.
$1) \ $ Set $u = x^n$.  This converts the problem to $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 \frac{u^\frac{1}{n}}{1+u^\frac{3}{n}} \, du$ and now using the bounded convergence theorem this is trivially $1/2$
$2) \ $ Integrating by parts, setting $dv = nx^n \, dx$ and $u = \frac{1}{1+x^3}$.  Then $u(1) v(1) - u(0)v(0) = \frac{n}{2(n+1)}$ while $\displaystyle \lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int_0^1 v \, du = 0$ rather trivially
$3) \ $ Avoiding any calculus tricks:  Fix small $\epsilon > 0$ and write $\displaystyle \int_0^1 \frac{n x^n}{1+x^3} \, dx = \int_0^{1-\epsilon} \frac{n x^n}{1+x^3} \, dx + \int_{1-\epsilon}^1 \frac{n x^n}{1+x^3} \, dx$.  As $n \rightarrow \infty$ the first integral converges to zero by uniform convergence.  In the second one, we have $\frac12 \leq \frac{1}{1 + x^3} \leq \frac{1}{1 + (1-\epsilon)^3}$ while $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{1-\epsilon}^1 nx^n \, dx = 1$.
To make this precise, the easiest thing (in my opinion) is to play with $\liminf$ and $\limsup$ and then let $\epsilon \rightarrow 0^+$, which (again in my opinion) makes performing $3)$ very useful pedagogical (as is breaking an integral up and estimating each piece, instead of using calculus).
So my question is: are there similar examples as above (concrete examples where the standard limit theorems of integration don't apply) where you $\textit{can't}$ use calculus tricks to evaluate the limit, and where you $\textit{must}$ estimate like in $3)$ (or estimate in a more sophisticated manner?)

I have always have been of the opinion that a single $u$ substitution will exist for all of these kinds of limit integrals. Having said that, $u$ substitutions get unwieldy and less practical the higher order behavior you want to poke. In your example you found the the first order limit but can you find $$L_2=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1\frac{nx^n}{1+x^3}-\frac{1}{2}dx$$ or further $$L_3=\lim_{n\to\infty}n\int_0^1\frac{n^2x^n}{1+x^3}-\frac{n}{2}-L_2dx$$ ?

here is a tangentially related problem I like which your question reminds me of: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2856511/sum-of-poisson-distributions

Ninad, this is an interesting point!  I'll take a look at this!

Laplace’s Method:
\begin{align}
& \color{#44f}{\Large\lim_{n \to \infty}\int_{0}^{1}{nx^{n} \over 1 + x^{3}}{\rm d}x}\,\,
\stackrel{x\ \mapsto\ 1 - x}{=}\
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[n\int_{0}^{1}{\left(1 - x\right)^{n} \over 1 + \left(1 - x\right)^{3}}{\rm d}x\right]
\\[5mm] = & \
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[n\int_{0}^{1}
{\exp\left(n\ln\left(1 - x\right)\right) \over 1 + \left(1 - x\right)^{3}}{\rm d}x\right]
\\[5mm] = & \
\lim_{n \to \infty}\left[n\int_{0}^{\infty}
{\exp\left(-nx\right) \over 1 + \left(1 - 0\right)^{3}}{\rm d}x\right] = \color{#44f}{\Large {1 \over 2}}
\end{align}

This isn't related to the question.
